# Tooltip text doesn't show on hovering

Tags: html, css, hover, tooltip

Here is a simple gallery and I want to show a tooltip text on days hover. In that case I want to show newyear text on 1. January hover. I took tooltip code from w3schools. Do I have a logical error or syntactical?

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

thead {
  width: 300px !important;
}

td {
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  font: 87.5%/1.5em 'Lato', sans-serif;
  left: 50%;
  background: #ccc;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.calendar-container {
  position: relative;
}

.calendar-container header {
  border-radius: 1em 1em 0 0;
  background: #e66b6b;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 402px;
}

.newyear .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.newyear .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.newyear:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.month {
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 1em;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.calendar {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0 0 1em 1em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 3px 1px #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 3px 1px #fff;
  color: #555;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
}

.calendar thead {
  color: #e66b6b;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.calendar td {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.calendar tbody td:hover {
  background: #cacaca;
}

.current-day {
  color: #e66b6b;
  background: #cacaca;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.prev-month,
.next-month {
  color: #cacaca;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="calendar-container">

    <header>


      <div class="month">Januar</div>

    </header>

    <table class="calendar">

      <thead>

        <tr>

          <td>Mon</td>
          <td>Tue</td>
          <td>Wed</td>
          <td>Thu</td>
          <td>Fri</td>
          <td>Sat</td>
          <td>Sun</td>

        </tr>

      </thead>

      <tbody>

        <tr>
          <td class="prev-month">29</td>
          <td class="prev-month">30</td>
          <td class="prev-month">31</td>
          <td class="newyear">1<span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span> </td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td class="current-day">18</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>31</td>
          <td class="next-month">1</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>

    </table>



  </div>
  <!-- end calendar-container -->

</div>
<!-- end container -->
```

[View on Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/opeoep)

Answer (score 1):

The containing element, of the tooltip, needs to be *positioned*, so that the tooltip appears "relatively" from the containing element (`.newyear`) when hovering over it.

This can be done by declaring the `position` property to the containing element (`.newyear`) of the *absolutely* positioned nested element (`.tooltiptext`) e.g:

```
.newyear {
  position: relative;
}
```

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

thead {
  width: 300px !important;
}

td {
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  font: 87.5%/1.5em 'Lato', sans-serif;
  left: 50%;
  background: #ccc;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.calendar-container {
  position: relative;
}

.calendar-container header {
  border-radius: 1em 1em 0 0;
  background: #e66b6b;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 402px;
}

.newyear .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.newyear .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.newyear:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.newyear {
  position: relative;
}

.month {
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 1em;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.calendar {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0 0 1em 1em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 3px 1px #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 3px 1px #fff;
  color: #555;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
}

.calendar thead {
  color: #e66b6b;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.calendar td {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.calendar tbody td:hover {
  background: #cacaca;
}

.current-day {
  color: #e66b6b;
  background: #cacaca;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.prev-month,
.next-month {
  color: #cacaca;
}
```

```html
<table class="calendar">

  <thead>

    <tr>

      <td>Mon</td>
      <td>Tue</td>
      <td>Wed</td>
      <td>Thu</td>
      <td>Fri</td>
      <td>Sat</td>
      <td>Sun</td>

    </tr>

  </thead>

  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td class="prev-month">29</td>
      <td class="prev-month">30</td>
      <td class="prev-month">31</td>
      <td class="newyear">1<span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span> </td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>11</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>17</td>
      <td class="current-day">18</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>25</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>26</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>31</td>
      <td class="next-month">1</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>
```

*In Summary:*

The tooltip is taken *out of the normal document flow* when *positioned absolute* (e.g: `position: absolute`) and positioned relative to the document.

To place it *relative* to a parent (containing) element, that parent element must be *positioned relative* - the tooltip is now *positioned relative to the parent element*.

Comment: I also recommend not limiting the tooltip functionality to the `.newyear` element. Might as well have it work within any `<td>`.

Answer (score 0):

Just change these properties on your this class:

```
.newyear .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  /*z-index: 1;*/
  /*bottom: 125%;*/
  left: 50%;
  /* margin-left: -60px; */ 
  top:20%; /* New line */
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

I did commented `"/* */"` the troubleshooting lines. I didn't erase any of them that way you can see what you were doing wrong. Here you can see your working tooltip above number "1" of the new year:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

thead {
  width: 300px !important;
}

td {
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  font: 87.5%/1.5em 'Lato', sans-serif;
  left: 50%;
  background: #ccc;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.calendar-container {
  position: relative;
}

.calendar-container header {
  border-radius: 1em 1em 0 0;
  background: #e66b6b;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 402px;
}

.newyear .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  /*z-index: 1;*/
  /*bottom: 125%;*/
  left: 50%;
  /* margin-left: -60px; */ 
  top:20%; /* New line */
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.newyear .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.newyear:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.month {
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 1em;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.calendar {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0 0 1em 1em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 3px 1px #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 3px 1px #fff;
  color: #555;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
}

.calendar thead {
  color: #e66b6b;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.calendar td {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.calendar tbody td:hover {
  background: #cacaca;
}

.current-day {
  color: #e66b6b;
  background: #cacaca;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.prev-month,
.next-month {
  color: #cacaca;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="calendar-container">

    <header>


      <div class="month">Januar</div>

    </header>

    <table class="calendar">

      <thead>

        <tr>

          <td>Mon</td>
          <td>Tue</td>
          <td>Wed</td>
          <td>Thu</td>
          <td>Fri</td>
          <td>Sat</td>
          <td>Sun</td>

        </tr>

      </thead>

      <tbody>

        <tr>
          <td class="prev-month">29</td>
          <td class="prev-month">30</td>
          <td class="prev-month">31</td>
          <td class="newyear">1<span class="tooltiptext">Happy New Year!</span> </td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td class="current-day">18</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>31</td>
          <td class="next-month">1</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>

    </table>



  </div>
  <!-- end calendar-container -->

</div>
<!-- end container -->
```